# Ignoring empty files from coverage report

Tags: python, code-coverage

[Coverage.py](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy) will include `__init__.py` in its report and show it as 0 lines, but with 100% coverage.

I want to exclude all blank files from the coverage report. I can't just add `*/__init__.py` to `omit` as some of my `__init__.py` files have code.

Comment: I was about to ask this same question.  I'd like to figure this out too.

Comment: I was looking for the answer to this and only found this question...

Comment: I have asked in the issue tracker for this feature: https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issue/315/option-to-omit-empty-files-eg-__init__py

A workaround could be to autogenerate a `.coveragerc` file, where you add all empty files to `[run] omit`..

Comment: Consider accepting my answer, please.

Answer (score 19):

From the [docs](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#report) and [docs](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_coverage.html#coverage.Coverage.report): "New in version 5.0: The `contexts` and `skip_empty` parameters." In your `tox.ini` file or `.coveragerc` file add the following:

```
[coverage:report]
skip_empty = true
```

> "If skip_empty is true, don’t report on empty files (those that have
> no statements)."
>
> "skip_empty (boolean, default False): Don’t include empty files (those
> that have 0 statements) in the report. See Coverage summary for more
> information."

Comment: Add it to [setup.cfg](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/tutorial/tests/#running-the-tests) for flask.

Answer (score 8):

This feature doesn't exist in coverage.py.  Does it help that you can sort the HTML report to move 100% files to the bottom, or files with 0 statements to the bottom?

UPDATE: As of coverage.py 4.0, the `--skip-covered` option is available to do exactly what is requested.

Comment: It would be nice if coverage.py considered empty files as `covered` or allowed for their exclusion.

Comment: From the docs: "The --skip-covered switch will leave out any file with 100% coverage." So it will skip both files with 0 or many statements. OP asked to just skip empty files, so not exactly.

Answer (score 7):

I set pyproject.toml like this:

```
[tool.coverage]
    [tool.coverage.run]
    omit = [
        # omit anything in a .local directory anywhere
        '*/.local/*',
        '__init__.py',
        'tests/*',
        '*/tests/*',
        # omit anything in a .venv directory anywhere
        '.venv/*'
    ]

    [tool.coverage.report]
    skip_empty = true
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the .coveragerc file like this:

```
[run]
omit = test/* \
       *\__init__.py
```

or

```
[run]
omit = com*\__init__.py \ 
       test/*
```

it seems that omit do not allow pattern startwith asterisk (*)

Comment: Asterisk at beginning worked for me under the `[run]` section, e.g.: `omit = */__init__.py`. I'm using pytest 5.0.1 and `cov`-plugin version 2.7.1 (i.e. pytest-cov).

Answer (score 2):

`coverage report` now supports the `--skip-empty` directive, which will conveniently omit those empty `__init__.py` files, while continuing to include any with contents!

Adapted from the docs

- `--skip-empty` skip any file with no executable statements
- `--skip-covered` skip any file with 100% coverage

https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cmd.html#coverage-summary

This has been available since [coverage 5.0](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/releases/tag/coverage-5.0b1) via [GitHub PR 864](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/pull/864)

Answer (score -1):

To exclude all empty files, i.e. files without any statements, and thus 100% coverage you can use:

```
$ coverage report | grep -v " 0      0      0      0   100%"
```

Unfortunately, this does not exclude those files from the coverage html report and is more cumbersome than a simple option.